# Remove special characters from keys of a parsed xml file using xmltodict

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, xmltodict

I have parsed an xml file using the `xmltodict` module and the result is stored in a dictionary of dictionaries.

Now I want to remove the special characters `@` and `#` in every key of the dictionary.

```
def remove_using_json(parse_result):
    data = {}
    data = json.dumps(parse_result)
    #print data
    #for d in data:
    for key, value in data.iterkeys():
        if key[0] == '@':
            data[key]=key.strip("@")
        elif key[0] == '#':
            data[key] =key.strip("#")
```

Comment: post your code you have so far tried...:)

Comment: def remove_using_json(parse_result):
    data = {}
    data = json.dumps(parse_result)
    #print data
     #for d in data:
     for key, value in data.iterkeys():
         if key[0] == '@':
             data[key]=key.strip("@")
         elif key[0] == '#':
             data[key] =key.strip("#")
     data.update(d)

Answer (score 17):

You shouldn't remove these special characters from your response.

There is an option not to get them in your response at all. ;-)

```
result = xmltodict.parse(response, attr_prefix='@', cdata_key='#text')
```

These are the default options, but you may set `attr_prefix=""` to get rid of `@` symbols, and change `cdata_key` in the same way.

Furthermore, you may also add `dict_constructor=dict` to create dictionaries in your parsed response instead of OrderDicts if you don't want to convert it back to XML with `xmltodict.unparse()`.

Comment: this is the correct answer and should be marked as

Answer (score 3):

To remove `@` from keys of dictionary use `attr_prefix=''` as argument to xmltodict.parse() function.
To remove `#` from keys of dictionary use `cdata_key='text'` as argument to `xmltodict.parse()` function.

> Text values for nodes can be specified with the `cdata_key` key in the python dict, while node properties can be specified with the `attr_prefix` prefixed to the key name in the python dict. The default value for `attr_prefix` is `@` and the default value for `cdata_key` is `#text`.

Click [here](https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to eliminate those during parsing as they are used to denote attributes and text nodes allowing them to be distinguished from elements (if they weren't there the output would be unusable).

For example

```
xmltodict.parse("""
    <root>
        <abc><def>ab</def></abc>
        <abc id="a3">efg</abc>
    </root>
""")
```

produces a nested ordered dict with the structure

```
{'root': {'abc': [ 
                     {'def': 'ab'},
                     {'@id': 'a3', '#text': 'efg'}
                 ]
         }
}
```

The **@** symbol tells me that the **@id** is an attribute.  Without that symbol, I couldn't tell if it was an attribute or an element named *id*.  Similarly, the **#** symbol tells me that **#text** is the text value of that element.  Without that I couldn't tell if it was the element's text, or if it was an element named *text*.

However, when dealing with the keys, you can strip them using `ky[1:]` where `ky` is the key.

For example, if I assign the above parsed output to the variable `doc`, I can do<sup>1</sup>

```
for abcelem in doc["root"]["abc"]:
    for ky in abcelem:
        if ky[0]=="@": print("Attribute:",ky[1:])
        elif ky[0]=="#": print("Text Content")
        else: print("Element:",ky)
```

Which would output

```
Element: def
Attribute: id
Text Content
```

where I have stripped the **@** symbol from the attribute.

---

If you really want to remove these symbols completely from the parsed value, you can write a recursive function to do this.

```
def remover(x):
    if isinstance(x,list): return [remover(y) for y in x]
    elif isinstance(x,OrderedDict):
        for ky in list(x.keys()):
            if ky[0] in ["@","#"]: 
                x[ky[1:]] = remover(x[ky])
                del x[ky]
            else: x[ky] = remover(x[ky])
        return x
    else: return x
```

Thus in the above, `remover(doc)` would remove all of the **@** and **#** symbols from the keys.  The behavior may be unstable and will lose some data if any node has an element and attribute with the same name or either an element or attribute named *text*, which is precisely why those symbols are there in the first place.  This function does modify the object in place, and thus, if the original needs to be preserved, a deepcopy should be made and passed to the function.

---

<sup>1</sup> This uses python 3 syntax, where the print command is a function.  To make this example work in python 2.6 or 2.7, first issue `from __future__ import print_function` or change the print function calls to statements like `print "Attribute: "+ky[1:]`.

Comment: What does it means? `['def': 'ab', ]` Is it list or dict?

Comment: @AlexBelyaev It means that I forgot a set of curly braces ;-)

Comment: Happy to help you ;)

Answer (score 1):

It happens because your function doesn't go 'in depth'. So let's get a sample dict from @Matthew answer for example:

```
d = xmltodict.parse("""
    <root>
        <abc><def>ab</def></abc>
        <abc id="a3">efg</abc>
    </root>
""")

In [29]: d
Out[29]: {'root': {'abc': [{'def': 'ab'}, {'#text': 'efg', '@id': 'a3'}]}}
```

Your function will find only one key in this dict: `root`. But you can iterate over all items recursively in a way like that:

```
# What if you use different from dict Mapping implementation
# ...like OrderedDict or defaultdict? So lets check type 
# ...of the nested 'dicts' with Mapping interface
from collections import Mapping

def transform(element, strip_chars="#@"):
    if isinstance(element, Mapping):
        return {key.strip(strip_chars): transform(value) 
                    for key, value 
                    in element.iteritems()}
    elif isinstance(element, list):
        return [transform(item) for item in element]
    else:
        return element

In [27]: d1 = transform(d)

In [28]: d, d1
Out[28]: 
({'root': {'abc': [{'def': 'ab'}, {'#text': 'efg', '@id': 'a3'}]}},
 {'root': {'abc': [{'def': 'ab'}, {'id': 'a3', 'text': 'efg'}]}})
```